# How to add eCommerce transaction for specific date?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have implemented eCommerce tracking in my asp.net website after 4 orders has been placed from website. Due to this 1st four orders are not showing in my eCommerce tracker.
How can i add those orders with actual order date in google analytic eCommerce order tracking so that date wise filtration will work fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can't the date and time are recorded when the hit is sent to Google Analytics.  This is not something you can update after the hit has taken place.

The best you can do is insert them now the date and time of the order will be now though.